# How to allow-list certain IP ranges in MySQL settings to use Google Apps Script

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, ip-address, whitelist

I am finding a way to connect MySQL to Google Spreadsheet and one of the ways that I found was to use the Google Apps Script. But before using, need to allow list certain IP address from Google. I have look through the resources online but still can't find proper steps to add allow list to MySQL. Does someone have experience and figure out how to do it before?

Comment: Why would you need to whitelist anything? Paste your code example

Comment: var server = '127.0.0.1';
var port = 3306;
var dbName = 'project';
var username = 'root';
var password = 1234567;
var url = 'jdbc:mysql://'+server+':'+port+'/'+dbName;

function readData() {
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM employee');

Comment: >> this is the code that I put inside my Apps Script to get MySQL connection, but I get "Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password" when I run. All the database details are correct then I suspect that is becuase I haven't allow list certain ip addresses, so Apps Script cannot access MySQL

Comment: by any chance you running MySQL 8, check this thread: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119660771

Comment: Thanks Kos! I have checked the thread above, so, to use the Google Apps Script I have to downgraded MySQL to version 5 or else I have to use third-party tools?

Comment: well, you can add "star" to the issue at issue tracker or leave a comment there with your use case, and wait until Google fixes it, but to be fair, it's not going to happen [in near future]

Comment: also may be related to this outage: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/192813431

Comment: check this announcement: `Note: The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver was updated to version 7.2.1 on Monday, August 9, 2021.` from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the Allow-List issue - as I'm also searching for how to add the ~70 Google URLs to MySQL 8.0 config file.

BUT, I *have* just finally managed to connnect to MySQL from Google Sheets.

1. You cannot connect from Google Sheets to 'Localhost' (127.0.0.1) as you are trying to do, because Sheets runs on a Google server. Therefore, you have to allow external access to your db.
2. It appears that the default MySQL installation does not include a 'bind-address' parameter in the config file, my.ini! Years ago, there was a default entry of `bind-address=127.0.01` which would only allow local connections. I manually added `bind-address=0.0.0.0`, which allows all external access. This will at least allow you to test your connection from Sheets, although I too want to restrict access to the 70 URLs at [Google Allow-List](https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt).

I had to take a few other steps before I could successfully connect; you might like to read through my post at [Connect Google Sheets to MySQL on Localhost - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68758243/connect-google-sheets-to-mysql-on-localhost) as it has links to resources I found.