# Connect Google Sheets to MySQL on Localhost

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Just installed MySQL locally, and created a db and one simple table. I'm now trying to connect to it from Google Sheets, but it fails with err:

`{ [Exception: Invalid argument: url] name: 'Exception' } undefined`

Much googling later, it seems that because Sheets runs on google servers, it can't resolve `localhost` as a Host.

Is there a way around this?

```
var HOST      = 'localhost';
var PORT      = '3306';
var USERNAME  = 'xxxx';
var PASSWORD  = 'xxxx';
var DATABASE  = 'investment';
var DB_TYPE   = 'mysql';
var MAXROWS   = 1000;

function testConnection(){
    var sql = doc.getRange('query!a2').getDisplayValue();
    var options = {};
}
function runSql(query, options) {
    try {
        var fullConnectionString = 'jdbc:' + DB_TYPE + '://' + HOST + ':' + PORT;
        var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(fullConnectionString, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        Logger.log('conn :', conn);
        Logger.log('query :', query);
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute('USE ' + DATABASE);
        var start = new Date();
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setMaxRows(MAXROWS);
        var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, e.lineNumber);
        Browser.msgBox(e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just wondering, if I could find a way of getting my IPv4 address online (since it would be DHCP I think, so changing periodically), could I use Host such as `101.146.72.23/localhost`?  (*not my real IP*)

**[Edit]** I tried adding my IPv4 address as above, and maybe that took me a step closer, as now I get a different error:

`{ [Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.] name: 'Exception' } undefined`

While reading up on [Google: JDBC](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc), it states "*In order to create a database connection using the JDBC service you must allow-list certain IP ranges in your database settings to allow Apps Script to access it. These are the address ranges you'll need to allow-list.*"

Now searching on how to do this in Windows 10.

**[Edit 2]** Reporting progress for anyone else who needs to do this. Following @Julian Benavides suggestions, I found a link on how to [Add Port Forwarding on Telstra Smart Modem](https://portforward.com/telstra/smart-modem-gen-2/) . This post pointed out that my pc would need a Static IP address (on the local network), at [How to Setup a Static IP Address on a Computer](https://portforward.com/networking/staticip.htm).

I *think* I have made a successful connection, although now I have to figure out why I have error:

`Exception: Table 'investment.investment_type' doesn't exist`

Getting closer, but no cigar yet.

**[Edit 3 - Success!]** I had the wrong table name, now works!

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure a port forwarding or DMZ access ?, if you are at home configure and do access to router or contact with your ISP, or if you are in the company contact with the network administrator.

With this way your ip could be resolve in internet and be accesed by jdbc connection.

Comment: Hi Julian.  In Australia, I'm connected to our "National Broadband Network" (NBN) via Telstra (an ISP).  The modem is supplied by Telstra as well. I don't know what port forwarding or DMZ are, can you suggest anywhere on the net to get some info perhaps?

Comment: Telstra (un ISP) can help you, contact them, more information https://www.telstra.com.au/platinum-technical-support/articles/port-forwarding

Comment: Thanks, I tried to get to the modem on 10.0.0.138, but no response. It's 2am here, so I'll try to contact Telstra tomorrow. Cheers, Max

Comment: Finally, after wading through quite a few obsolete instructions, I connected to the Smart Modem Gen 2 on 192.168.0.1, and then added a Port Forwarding (3306) entry for MySQL to a newly-created Static IP on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

A brief summary of how the issue was resolved - more info in the updates in the original post.

1. **The code** I used was closely derived from [Ben Collins - How To Connect Google Sheets To A Database, Using Apps Script](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/how-to-connect-google-sheets-to-a-database/)
2. @Julian Benavides pointed out that I needed to add **Port Forwarding**, found how to do that at [Setup a Port Forward on the Telstra Smart Modem Gen 2 Router](https://portforward.com/telstra/smart-modem-gen-2/)
3. Had to assign a **Static IP** on my local network for the machine running MySQL, from [How to Setup a Static IP Address](https://portforward.com/networking/staticip.htm)

Hope this may be useful to another novice like me. :)

Comment: hello, I am myself in a similar situation and would like a few explanations : is setting a static IP address necessary if I am willing to change it manually in the app script (I only need to set it up for a demonstration), if not I would only need to do the port forwarding part ?