# How can I connect Google appscript with MySQL localhost?

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script

I have tried many times using Google Apps Script to connect to MySQL localhost. Additionally, I have experimented with AI tools like BARD and ChatGPT, but I am unable to establish a connection. Actually, I have MySQL installed on the same PC. I have also read Google's documentation where they provided some IP ranges and ports to whitelist, and I have done this as well. However, I am still unable to achieve success. Can anyone help me with this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
const connectionName = 'localhost';
const rootPwd = '';
const user = 'root';
const userPwd = '';
const db = 'employee_db';

const root = 'root';
const instanceUrl = 'jdbc:google:mysql://' + connectionName;
const dbUrl = instanceUrl + '/' + db;

function createDatabase() {
  try {
    const conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(instanceUrl, root, rootPwd);
    conn.createStatement().execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + db);
  } catch (err) {
    // TODO(developer) - Handle exception from the API
    console.log('Failed with an error %s', err.message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your local network have a static IP? Related question [Connect Google Sheets to MySQL on Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68774496/1330560)

Comment: No it was dynamic, I thought this option to so for that I have change connection name to Localhost.

Comment: Right, but Google Sheets is an app that is hosted in the cloud NOT your PC; so it is looking for an IP address where it can find your database. Have you read that Question, comments and answer?

Comment: then can you please Help me with this code if possible.

Comment: **Have you read that Question, comments and answer?**